# Why have my two different portable Thunderbird have stopped working on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, crash

I have two separate portable Thunderbird .exes on my laptop.

Suddenly today while working, the Thunderbird that was open said that it "had stopped working" and shut down with the following error message:

[image]

*"The program has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."*

- When I try to start the other Thunderbird, I get the same message.
- Sometimes they don't start at all and I never get a message.
- I have rebooted several times, but it has not helped the problem.
- I copied the full .exe and all the sub-directories (App, Data, Other) to a USB drive and started it there but the same thing happens.
- I downloaded a new version of Thunderbird portable, installed it in a new directory, copied the App, Data, Other directories over, and it starts but then after 10 seconds gets the same error.

**What is causing my Thunderbirds to crash and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

What helped for me is that I started Thunderbird in safe mode (`thunderbird -safe-mode`) and waited until everything was quiet. Then I could start it normally again.